# Django-Vue error "Failed to mount app: mount target selector returned null."

Tags: python, django, vue.js

Thanks for looking into my problem, I am a beginner with Django and Vue your assistance with this wil be extremely helpful. I am working on a Job portal and created the job search functionality in Django as backend for the same I have an app called **job** into my Django project. The browser Js console gives this error `Failed to mount app: mount target selector returned null.` For this app I have an add job view, through which an employer adds the jobs. For this I'm using Vue for validation and showing any errors if any non-null fields are not entered by the employer account. So this is not how it was supposed to look,[Unexpected results snap shot](https://github.com/pawan-nirpal-031/Python_Projects/blob/master/fault2.jpg) so as you can see it wasn't supposed to give me `[[error]]` and `company_size` instead `The company size is missing` as per the Vue AddJobApp, given below. Also if were to add **#** within mount-function-createapp within Vue-AddJobApp, the page entirely disappears (blank page). what am I doing wrong here?

```
adding # in AddJob.mount() function is making the page go blank a
```

Add job template

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}


{% block content %}

        <div id="add-job-app">

            <h1 class="title"> Add Job</h1>
            <form action="." method="POST" v-on:submit="validateForm">
                {% csrf_token %}

                {% if form.errors %}
                    {% for error in form.errors %}
                        <div class="notification is-danger">
                            {{ error }}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
                    
                <div class="notification is-danger" v-if ="error.length" >
                    <p v-for="error in errors" >
                        [[ error ]]
                    </p>
                </div>
                        
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="">Title</label>
                    
                    <div class="control">
                        <input class="input" type="text" name="title" id="id_title" v-model= "title">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <label for="">Short description</label>
                    
                    <div class="control">
                        <textarea name="short_description" id="id_short_description" class="textarea" v-model= "short_description" ></textarea>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <label for="">Long description</label>
                    
                    <div class="control">
                        <textarea name="long_description" id="id_long_description" class="textarea" v-model= "long_description" ></textarea>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <label for="">Company name</label>
                    
                    <div class="control">
                        <input class="input" type="text" name="company_name" id="id_company_name"  v-model= "company_name"  >
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <label for="">Company address</label>
                    
                    <div class="control">
                        <input class="input" type="text" name="company_address" id="id_company_address" v-model= "company_address">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <label for="">Company zipcode</label>
                    
                    <div class="control">
                        <input class="input" type="text" name="company_zipcode" id="id_company_zipcode" v-model= "company_zipcode">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <label for="">Company place</label>
                    
                    <div class="control">
                        <input class="input" type="text" name="company_place" id="id_company_place" v-model= "company_place">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <label for="">Company Country</label>
                    
                    <div class="control">
                        <input class="input" type="text" name="company_country" id="id_company_country" v-model= "company_country">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <label for="">Company Size</label>
                    
                    <div class="control">
                        <div class="select">
                            <select name="company_size"  v-model = "company_size">
                                <option value="">Choose Size</option>
                                <option value="size_1_9">1-9</option>
                                <option value="size_10_49">10-49</option>
                                <option value="size_50_99">50-99</option>
                                <option value="size_100">100+</option>
                            </select>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>



                <div class="field">
                    <div class="control">
                        <button class="button is-success">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
        <script >
            const AddJobApp = {
                data() {
                    return {
                        title:'',
                        company_name:'',
                        short_description:'',
                        company_size:'',
                        errors:[]
                    }
                },
                delimiters:['[[',']]'],
                methods :{
                    validateForm(e){
                        this.errors = []

                        if( this.title ===''){
                            this.errors.push('The title field is missing')
                        }
                        
                        if( this.short_description   ===''){
                            this.errors.push('The short description field is missing')
                        }
                        
                        if( this.company_name  ===''){
                            this.errors.push('The company name field is missing')
                        }
                        
                        if( this.company_size  ===''){
                            this.errors.push('The company size is missing')
                        }

                        if(this.errors.length){
                           e.preventDefault()
                           return false
                        }else{
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Vue.createApp(AddJobApp).mount('add-job-app');
        </script>
{% endblock %}
```

my views.py file inside of **job** app

```
from apps.job.forms import AddJobForm, ApplicationForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from .models import Job
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from apps.notification.utilities import create_notification

def job_detail(request,job_id):
    job = Job.objects.get(pk=job_id)
    return render(request, 'job/job_detail.html',{'job':job})

def search(request):
    return render(request,'job/search.html')

@login_required
def apply_for_job(request,job_id):
    job = Job.objects.get(pk=job_id)

    if request.method=='POST':
        form = ApplicationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            application = form.save(commit=False)
            application.job = job
            application.created_by = request.user
            application.save()
            create_notification(request, job.created_by  ,'application',extra_id=application.id)
            return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        form = ApplicationForm()

    return render(request,'job/apply_for_job.html',{'form':form,'job':job})



@login_required
def add_job(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = AddJobForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            job = form.save(commit=False)
            job.created_by  = request.user
            job.save()
            return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        form = AddJobForm()

    return render(request,'job/add_job.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: Should be `<div id="search-app">`

Comment: Where exactly, right after the block content , instead of class

Comment: Yeah it worked!!

Comment: @Dan it did not seem to work with similar kind of error that I mentioned with other view within same job app, can you look into the question once again as I've edited it significantly

Comment: You removed the `#` in `mount`.  Use smaller code until you identify the issue or receive an error message

Comment: @Dan that's what I said carefully read it again as I changed it significantly, the last two lines of the question I've mentioned problem regarding use of ```#``` it gives blank page

Comment: @Dan can you please look into this again, this exact same error showed up in the previous version of this question however it got resolved but this is exact same kind of error that is not getting resolved please take a look, It would be huge help

Comment: You're still not using a `#`, it's not optional.  What errors are there in the console when it's a blank page?